# How to renumber an ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>

Tags: c#, .net, observablecollection, key-value

I'm binding a ObservableCollection with Key/Value -> int (index) and string to a Textbox in an ItemsControl.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value , Mode=OneWay}" />
```

If you click on a button in the ItemsControl, you can delete an item in the Collection.

```
private ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, String>> testlist;

public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, String>> TestList
{
    get { return testlist;  }
    set {
        testlist = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TestList");
    }
}

public void DeleteItem(int index)
{
    TestList.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Now I want to renumber the index (int) of the collection for example:

- Collection before removing an item: 0 - "aaa", 1 - "bbb", 2 - "ccc", 3 - "ddd"
- Collection after removing an item: 0 - "aaa", 2 - "ccc", 3 - "ddd"
- Collection after renumbering: 0 - "aaa", **1** - "ccc", **2** - "ddd"

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want that items keep previous ordering?

Comment: Are you sure you need a KeyValuePair at all, seems like a simple enumerable will do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project a new `ObservableCollection` after removing the item:

```
Testlist.RemoveAt(1);
Testlist = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>>(Testlist
    .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
    .Select((kvp, seq) => new KeyValuePair<int, String>(seq, kvp.Value)));
```

Notes

- The OrderBy preserves the Ordering
- Use the `Select` overload which provides the item index. Numbering from zero is assumed.

Comment: Shouldn't this order by the Key and not the Value?  Although the OP's example would work either way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works. One last question. If I have the collection with the key/values: 0/a, 2/c, 1/b, how can I sort them without changing the value like: 0/a, 1/c, 2/b?

Comment: @StuartLC My new question has nothing to do with the old question. I would just like to change all Keys in the ObservableCollection without changing the Values. Yes 0/a, 1/c, 2/b is a desirable outcome.

Comment: It looks like you just want to keep the original 'natural' order? Its then the same as the original answer, just without the `OrderBy` step? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by a `foreach`, but before that you need to sort them, since the key is read only, you should build a new collection

```
// Acquire keys and sort them.
var list = ObservableCollection.Keys.ToList();
list.Sort();

int i = 0;
var newList = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
foreach (var key in list)
{
     newList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(i, ObservableCollection[key].Value));
     i++;
}
```

However you could shift the items from the number at which the item was deleted

Comment: `KeyValuePair<K,V>.Key` is read only.  So you have to create new `KeyValuePair<int, string>` to make this work.

Comment: thanks, It seems I should delete my answer if no fix suggested

Comment: You should do `newList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(i, ObservableCollection[key].Value));`  The problem is that your newList is empty and you'll get an exception trying to set something to a specific index.

Comment: @juharr Thank you, it seems I mistook the question with an ordinary collection ;)